# v-model not always updating in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Short question**

The `v-model` which binds a string to an input field won't update in *some cases*.

**Example**

I am using Vue within a Laravel application. This is the main component which contains two other components:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select-component 
      :items="items" 
      @selectedItem="updateSelectedItems"
    />

    <basket-component 
      :selectedItems="selectedItems" 
      @clickedConfirm="confirm" 
      @clickedStopAll="stopAll"
    />

    <form ref="chosenItemsForm" method="post">
      <!-- Slot for CSRF token-->
      <slot name="csrf-token"></slot>
      <input type="text" name="chosenItems" v-model="selectedItemsPipedList" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["items"],
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedItems: [],
      selectedItemsPipedList: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateSelectedItems: function(data) {
      this.selectedItems = data;
      this.selectedItemsPipedList = this.selectedItems
        .map(item => item.id)
        .join("|");
    },
    confirm() {
        this.$refs.chosenItemsForm.submit();
    },
    stopAll() {
      this.updateSelectedItems([]);
      this.confirm();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The method `updateSelectedItems` is called from the `select-component` and it works fine. In the end, the `selectedItemsPipedList` contains the selected items from the `select-component`, which looks like `"1|2|3"` and this value is bound to the input field in the `chosenItemsForm`. When the method `confirm` is called from the `basket-component`, this form is posted to the Laravel backend and the post request contains the chosen items as piped list. So far, so good.

The method `stopAll` is called from the `basket-component` and it will remove all the selected items from the array. Therefore it will call the method `updateSelectedItems` with an empty array, which will clear the `selectedItems` array and then clear the `selectedItemsPipedList`. After that, confirm is called which will post the form again. But, the post value still contains the selected items (e.g. '1|2|3'), instead of `""`. It looks like the `v-model` in my form is not updated, which is strange because it does work when selecting items. Why is it working when adding items, and doesn't when removing all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a timing issue here. The value of the properties haven't been propagated to the DOM yet, so the form submission is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
stopAll() {
  this.updateSelectedItems([]);

  //NextTick waits until after the next round of UI updates to execute the callback.
  this.$nextTick(function() {this.confirm()});
}
```